# html5 canvas addEventListener separate function

Tags: html, canvas, addeventlistener

currently my code works with this method:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {....},false)
```

now I want to separate the function, make own function.
like:

```
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', myFunction(1), false)
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', myFunction(0), false)

  function myFunction (event, separator) {..}
```

but its not working

please help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for addEventListener is supposed to be a function reference (i.e. an object representing a function to be called in case of an event).

But you provide the `result of the call to myFunction()` as a parameter, which would only work if `myFunction` returned a function reference (i.e. if `myFunction` were a function factory).

```
function myFunction(myEvent, separator) {
   if(separator==0)
      return function(myEvent) {
         // your code goes here
      }
}
```